# How can I work with SpatialPolygons in 3D in R?

Tags: r, geospatial

I've got SpatialPolygons (which are defined in 2D) with associated start and end elevations.  I want to do 3D geospatial work with them, e.g. essentially extrude the 2D polygons between start and end elevations and then maybe do operations like union or intersection between the extruded polygons in 3D.

Having done some research, it seems that the popular packages like sp, rgeos, sf, all basically work only in 2D.  Given that, I figure I might have to try to handle the elevation side of things separately, either manually or using non-geospatial 3D packages for R.

I'm reaching out for confirmation that this is the case, and any help/suggestions on the best way to proceed would be much appreciated.